# Binding listview inside listview asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, listview

I want to bind listview inside the listview. I have an object which contains another object list object inside it.

Here I have result object and I have another weeklyresult(List) object in it.
I am trying to bind outer list with the result object.

Here is the cs code:

Populate data in resultListobject :

```
                ResultListView.DataSource = resultList;
                ResultListView.DataBind();
                Response.Write(resultList);
```

Classes Result and weeklyresult :

```
class Result {
    public string examDate { get; set; }
    public List<WeeklyResult> weeklyResultList = null;
}

class WeeklyResult {
    public string subject { get; set; }
    public double marksObtained { get; set; }
    public double outOff { get; set; }
}
```

Now here is my asp.net code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ResultListView" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server"></asp:Label>

            <table id="Table1" runat="server">
            <tr>
            <td>Date :<%#Eval("examDate")%> </td>
            <td>Marks Obtained</td>
            <td>Out off</td>
            </tr> </table>

                <asp:ListView ID="InnerListView" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label0"  runat="server" Text="abc<%#Eval('weeklyResultList.subject')%>"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>

            </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:ListView>
```

The data in the outer list is coming but nothing is getting displayed in the inner list.
Can you please suggest what I am doing wrong.

Thanks,
Amandeep

Answer (score 1):

Had to use:

```
DataSource='<%#Eval("weeklyResultList")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind inner ListView in first listView's [ItemDataBount Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Simply assign other DataSource. It will simply solve your problem...

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, but I believe it may help some people. Try this:

Datasource will be the name of the List inside the object

Change:

```
<asp:ListView ID="InnerListView" runat="server">
```

To:

```
<asp:ListView ID="InnerListView" runat="server" DataSource='<%#Eval("weeklyResultList")%>'>
```

And to access the attributes of each object in the list.

Change:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label0"  runat="server" Text="abc<%#Eval('weeklyResultList.subject')%>"></asp:Label>
```

To:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label0"  runat="server" Text="abc<%#Eval('subject')%>"></asp:Label>
```